# Passing array to library function

Tags: c++, library, array

I'm trying to pass an array to a library (written in c++) but the error:

```
undefined reference to `MyLib::arrayTest(int*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error compiling.
```

Is being produced.

My Code Is As Follows:

Testing.ino:

```
MyLib test = MyLib(5,4,6);

void setup(){
    int arr[10];

    test.arrayTest(arr);

    Serial.println(arr[0]);
}
```

MyLib.h:

```
class MyLib {
    public:
        MyLib(int x, int y, int z);

        void arrayTest(int* n);
```

MyLib.cpp:

```
void arrayTest(int* n){
    n[0] = 15;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `class MyLib` is incomplete.

Comment: I have that correct in the code I just made a mistake when posting the question, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function:

```
void arrayTest(int* n){
    n[0] = 15;
}
```

is lacking the class qualifier:

```
void MyLib::arrayTest(int* n){
    n[0] = 15;
}
```

Comment: @StackNinja Easily done. I have done it myself numerous times.